# Execute Method in User Control MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I am working on my first MVVM application and am having trouble getting it to work properly.

In my main window, I have a button that executes a SQL command that returns a custom data table type object.

The window also contains a user control that consists of a some column headers and a windows forms hosted DataGridView. I need to somehow tell the user control to execute a method that passes the data to the DataGridView so it can update it's values.

I tried creating a dependency property on my WPF Grid control that is bound to the data of my viewmodel, but it is not updating properly.

How can I get this to work?

--EDIT--

Here is the XAML for my LiteGrid usercontrol -

```
<UserControl x:Class="ReportUtility.Controls.LiteGrid.LiteGrid"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
         xmlns:lite="clr-namespace:ReportUtility.Controls.LiteGrid"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="_scroll" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Columns}" Grid.Row="0" Background="AliceBlue">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate> 
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <WindowsFormsHost Background="White" Grid.Row="1">
        <lite:LiteGridView x:Name="_liteGridView"/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

My main view model is:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    private readonly ILiteTableSource _source;

    public ICommand ExecuteQueryCommand { get; set; }
    public LiteGridViewModel Grid { get; set; }
    public string SqlCommandText { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel(ILiteTableSource source)
    {
        this.ExecuteQueryCommand = new ExecuteQueryCommand(this);

        _source = source;
        _source.DataArrived+=new Action<DataSources.LiteSource.LiteTable>(_source_DataArrived);
    }

    public void ExecuteQuery()
    {
        _source.Connection = new ServerConnection();
        _source.CommandText = this.SqlCommandText;
        _source.ExecuteQuery();
    }

    public LiteTable Results
    {
        get { return (LiteTable)GetValue(ResultsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ResultsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Results.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResultsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Results", typeof(LiteTable), typeof(MainWindowViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    void _source_DataArrived(LiteTable data)
    {

        this.Results = data;
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="TestButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Command="{Binding ExecuteQueryCommand}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=SqlCommandText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <lite:LiteGrid Grid.Row="2" Data="{Binding Data, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: LiteGrid is a self-made user control ?

Comment: Yes, it is pretty much a wrapper for the winformshost DataGridView that has the headers displayed in a stackpanel and the data in the winforms grid.

Comment: Your VM should (in most cases) not inherit from DependencyObject but implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) instead, no binding updates unless you bind to DPs (i do not see any in your code) or properties which fire notifications using that interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a `LiteGridViewModel` to go with your `LiteGrid`, why not just execute the command from the ViewModel?

Using the code posted in your question, I would:

Add this to the Resources to make sure that `LiteGridViewModel` is drawn using `LiteView`

```
<Window.Resources> <!-- Or Grid.Resources if you prefer -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type lite:LiteGridViewModel}">
        <lite:LiteGrid />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Replace the `<lite:LiteGrid ... />` control in the `MainView` with a ContentControl to display the ViewModel

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Grid}" />
```

Remove the `Data` Property on the `MainViewModel` since it should be stored in `LiteGridViewModel`, not `MainViewModel`

And in your `MainWindowViewModel` work with the `LiteGridViewModel` instead of trying to work with the ViewModel via the View

```
Grid = new LiteGridViewModel();

void _source_DataArrived(LiteTable data)
{
    Grid.Data = data;  // Fill property in ViewModel
    Grid.UpdateData(); // Call command on ViewModel
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this clears up a lot of my confusion. Everything is working now except that the visual grid is not getting refreshed correctly. I think it has to do with the viewmodel for the LiteGrid...How should this class be set up? Does the data template need to have any bindings for the results to be displayed?

Comment: --I have made an edit to the comment, I have included the XAML for my LiteGrid usercontrol. I have given the DataGridView an x:Name so I can address it directly from the LiteGrid control

Comment: The `LiteGrid` control inside the DataTemplate automatically has its DataContext set to `{Binding Grid}`, so no additional bindings are needed. I don't see a binding for your `LiteGridView` that is inside the `WindowsFormHost` though. Should there be one to give the `LiteGridView` some data?

Comment: Oh and you might want to remove the `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` in the UserControl tag. It is making the Control's DataContext become the `LiteGrid` control instead of the `LightGridViewModel`

Comment: Well, I am using a virtualized grid, it is being populated by the OnCellValueNeeded event.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that OnCellValueNeeded is not being called properly once I made the recommended changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public LiteTable Data
{
    get { return (LiteTable)GetValue(DataProperty); }
    set 
    {
        object oldvalue = Data;
        SetValue(DataProperty, value);
        OnPropertyChanged(new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs(DataProperty, oldvalue, value));
    }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(LiteTable), typeof(LiteGrid), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

try this...